# RuntimeError: No auth token found. Authentication Flow needed o365 python

Tags: python, linux, office365api

I'm using a Linux machine to run a python script within the Linux terminal.
If I open the terminal inside the directory that houses my python script then use `python3 availableHoursReporting.py` command the script runs without any issues.

However, if I open a terminal session outside of the directory that houses my python script then I get
`RuntimeError: No auth token found. Authentication Flow needed`

The directory structure is as follows on my Linux machine:

`/home/ubuntu/python_scripts/Available-Hours-Reporting-/`

The 'auth_token' is stored within the `Available-Hours-Reporting` folder

Here is the relevant code:

```
import o365
from o365 import Account

credentials = ('xxxxxxxxx',)

account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type = 'public')
account.connection.get_session(load_token = True)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/python_scripts/Available-Hours-Reporting-/availableHoursReporting.py", line 27, in <module>
    account.connection.get_session(load_token = True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/O365/connection.py", line 563, in get_session
    raise RuntimeError('No auth token found. Authentication Flow needed')
RuntimeError: No auth token found. Authentication Flow needed
```

I'm new to Linux so I'm not sure If I'm totally misunderstanding the folder structures or if I'm using the terminal correctly to execute the .py script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways to solve it.
method 1.

```
from o365.utils.token import FileSystemTokenBackend
tk = FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path="your token path", token_filename="filename")
account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type = 'public',token_backend=tk)
```

method 2. not use an instance of FileSystemTokenBackend

```
account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type = 'public',token_path="your token path", token_filename="filename")
```

You can find the details in the source code of "connection.py".
token_path should be a full absolute path.